# How can I set different textwidths for specific file extensions in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I would like to have a default textwidth of 80 characters except for a few file extensions like `txt`. The following lines appear to work, except for the first time when I edit (and create) a `txt` file.

```
setlocal textwidth=80
autocmd bufreadpre *.txt set textwidth=0
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

use `setlocal`

```
autocmd bufreadpre *.txt setlocal textwidth=0
```

instead of `set`.

With `setlocal` you make sure that the value you're setting is set in the current buffer, not for all buffers.

Comment: I changed to `setlocal`, but the problem continues to occur.

Comment: @PaulBaltescu : if you are editing a pre existing text file, `textwidth` alone will not modify the size of the line, you have to select all and use `gq` to wrap the lines.

Answer (score 11):

First, you've got the scopes the wrong way; use `:set` for the global default and `:setlocal` for the buffer-local override in the `:autocmd`.

Second, `BufReadPre` is only for reading existing files, not new ones; that's why it doesn't work the first time. Instead, you should use `BufNew,BufRead`; this captures both cases, and only applies *after* the file was read, so it will still work when you use *modelines* or have a setting in an *filetype plugin*.

Third, the `:autocmd` solution tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations. If you only want to enable a setting for certain filetypes, put the corresponding `:setlocal` commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`, where `<filetype>` is the actual filetype (e.g. `java`). (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`.)

Comment: Thank you. My only note is that if you have an exist in vim session saved and make this change, the settings won't propagate to the hpp or cpp files that exist already in there. However if you set up a new project with hpp and cpp files, this does work.  There was probably a work around for my case, but it was only 2 tabs and 4 files I had open, so it was pretty easy to just recreate the session.